# Ошибка при выполнении команды!

Tags: mingw, wxwidgets

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0

cpp: Too many arguments
makefile.gcc:5817: recipe for target 'gcc_mswud\wxregex_regcomp.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswud\wxregex_regcomp.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в компиляторе. У меня был установлен MINGW а нужен был TDM-GCC-32.